# Recursive fibonacci series not working well

Tags: c, recursion, user-defined-functions, fibonacci

I recently tried recursive programming in c and I tried to implement the same logic as a loop but in a recursive manner. I tried printing the answer in two places. One in the main function and one in the function I defined myself. The one in the user defined function gives the correct answer but  returning the value and printing it doesn't give the correct answer. Can you please help me identify what the issue is?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static int c,n, a=0,b=1;
int file (int n)
{
    
    if (n<=1)
    {
        printf ("%d",c);
        return c;
    }
    else
    {
        c = a+b;
        a = b;
        b = c;
        file ( n - 1 );
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int j;
    printf("Enter n: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    j = file(n);
    printf("\n%d",j);
    return 0;
}
```

This is what happens in the terminal,

tempCodeRunnerFile.c:20:1: warning: non-void function does not return a value in all control paths [-Wreturn-type]
}
^
1 warning generated.
Enter n: 9
34...32759%

Comment: Change `file(n-1)` to `return file(n-1);`

Comment: The warning `warning: non-void function does not return a value in all control paths` is pretty clear. Hint for the future: consider all warnings as errors.